# Pandas repeat rows for entire month when values for first of month present

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Month       Col1    Col2
1/1/2019    2       ca
2/1/2019    10      bg
```

I want to get the following:

```
Month     Col1  Col2
1/1/2019    2   ca
1/2/2019    2   ca
......rest days from 1/3 to 1/30 are here
1/31/2019   2   ca
2/1/2019    10  bg
2/2/2019    10  bg
-------
2/28/2019   10  bg
```

I am not sure how to implement this pythonically.

Edit: Month is not in index

Comment: Is month in the index?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
df.Month = pd.to_datetime(df.Month)
df = df.set_index(['Month'])[['Col1', 'Col2']]

def add_index(s):
    m = s.name
    index = pd.date_range(m, m + MonthEnd(n=1))
    o = s.to_frame().T.reindex(index)
    return o.ffill()
    
pd.concat([add_index(s) for d, s in df.iterrows()]).reset_index()
```